# input range slider on thumb/pointer move complete fire event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I am working with a HTML5 input range slider where API being called when user move pointer/thumb.

HTML

```
<input @change="myFunction($event)"  type="range" min="0" max="10" step="1" v-model="param7"  class="slider-color">
```

In all browser `@change` event firing after thumb/pointer move done. But same event  firing in IE11 when moving pointer. Thats why my API calling frequently in IE11 when pointer is moving.

But I need this works same as other browser so that API only call when pointer movement is complete. Is any other way to do it in vuejs or jquery?

my method

```
myFunction:function(e) {
  console.log('changed done');
}
```

This is outputting in IE `changed done` each time I touch pointer.

Comment: That's how IE11 behaves, you might end up going for a vue wrapper / plugin rangeslider checking first if it works on IE11 too, 
I did a lot of googling since you posted this and found tons of issues including reactjs and vuejs github issue pages. most of them claims that it's an ie11 issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it by adding 2 method, one for normal browser & other for IE using `@mouseup`

```
<input @change="myFunction($event)" @mouseup="myFunctionIE($event)" type="range" min="0" max="10" step="1" v-model="param7"  class="slider-color">
```

and now function

```
myFunction:function(e) {
  if(IE){
    return false;
  }
}
```

for IE

```
myFunctionIE:function(e) {
  if(!IE){
    return false;
  }
}
```

So I put same code but with different name function & its working as required